# Please help me with this complex variables integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Compute the following :$$\int z^n (1-z)^m dz $$ 
for any integer n and m. (Integral is done on the circle $|z|=2$)

I am just stuck from the start. Should I use Cauchy's Theorem of integral? Since n and m are arbitrary integers, I don't think integrating by parts is a useful way. Can anyone help me?

Comment: "Should I use Cauchy's Theorem of integral?" That is an excellent idea.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry but I am stuck from there... what if n and m are both bigger than 0?

Comment: There's a difference between Cauchy's integral theorem and Cauchy's integral formula (though they are closely related, and ultimately, both special cases of the residue theorem). The integral theorem immediately handles the case $m,n\geqslant 0$. The integral formula immediately handles the cases $m < 0 \leqslant n$ and $n < 0 \leqslant m$. For the case $m,n < 0$, you need to manipulate the integrand a little or combine the integral theorem with the integral formula.

Comment: @DanielFischer Okay thanks, I think I got a clue

Answer (score 0):

When $m,n\ge 0$, the integral theorem does the job.

Suppose at least one of $m,n$ is negative. if you are familiar with the concept of residue at infinity, this is the way to go.

And even if you are not, it still is. The function has a Laurent expansion in $|z|>1$, namely   $f(z) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} c_n z^n$. When integrated over a circle, only $z^{-1}$ contributes something, namely $2\pi i c_{-1}$.

If both $m,n$ are negative, then $zf(z)\to 0$ as $z\to\infty$. Hence, $c_{-1}=0$.

If $m\ge 0$, then from
$$      z^{n }(z-1)^m  = z^n \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k} z^k (-1)^{m-k}$$
you get the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ at once.

If $n\ge 0$, writing $\zeta=z-1$ you get 
$$      z^{n }(z-1)^m  = \zeta^m \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \zeta^k  $$
where the coefficient of $\zeta^{-1}$ again gives $c_{-1}$.